# Mono does not honor System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute EmitDefaultValue setting

Tags: c#, json, serialization, mono, portability

Tried the code in Visual Studio on Windows to be sure.

Mono framework does not appear to honor the `EmitDefaultValue` argument of the `DataMemberAttribute`. Using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MyApp
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Cereal specialK = new Cereal();
            specialK.TheValue="This is a what?";

            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Cereal));
            MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(stm, specialK);
            string json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stm.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    class Cereal
    {
        [DataMember(Name="set_on_serialize")]
        private string _setOnSerialize = string.Empty;

        [DataMember(Name = "default_export", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        private string _default_null;

        public Cereal() { }

        [DataMember(Name = "out_value")]
        public string TheValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [OnSerializing]
        void OnSerializing(StreamingContext content)
        {
            this._setOnSerialize = "A brick!";
        }
    }
}
```

The output in Mono results in:

```
{"default_export":null,"out_value":"This is a what?","set_on_serialize":""}
```

The default_export property is being exported as null but should not be output as it is the default value of type `string`.

Correct output from VS on Windows is:

```
{"out_value":"This is a what?","set_on_serialize":"A brick!"}
```

Is this a bug in Mono or am I missing something?

Comment: report this bug on http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

Comment: Also, please include version numbers in your questions, especially when pointing to possible bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this feature is not yet implemented in mono. See the [FIXME comment in the mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel.Web/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json/TypeMap.cs#L197) (line 197).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's in process now that I logged the bug.